# Is there any way to change selected items colour in inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

[image]

Is there any way to change selected items colour in inno setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Windows-theme thing. I suppose by 'Personalizing' windows you can modify them.

There is no way how to do it in Inno Setup.

Comment: Can i do this by editing Codejock skin (*.cjstyles)?

Comment: If Codejock skins support this feature then yes.